# How to loop certain HTML Elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I've read a lot about "looping" but I'm not sure you how to loop these elements above:

```
$("#equipment1").click(Image1Click)
$("#equipment2").click(Image2Click)
$("#equipment3").click(Image3Click)
$("#equipment4").click(Image4Click)
$("#equipment5").click(Image5Click)
```

I understand that the numbers would be `i` but I am stuck from here.

UPDATE:

Image2Click etc are functions that do DIFFERENT things and therefore I couldn't use a class to do this

Comment: Suggestions: 1. Use a `class` and 2. Use **one** generic event handler function.

Comment: See css and javascript documentation, will be a lot useful.

Comment: Not sure why my question was rated so badly

Comment: `Image2Click etc are functions that do DIFFERENT things and therefore I couldn't use a class to do this`, well but you can use a class yet. You only will need to check the id to do different things depending on it, inside the generic event handler function.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @techfoobar:

this is how your code should be written:

change your HTML to something like this

```
<div class="clickable-equipment" your-data="e1"></div>
```

and your JavaScript code now will do the following

```
$('.clickable-equipment').click(function(/* see jQuery Documentation of function options */){
var equipment = $(this).attr('your-data'); 

// now equipment = "e1"
// keep processing from here...
});
```

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = [];

myArray[] = {key: "#equipment1", value: Image1Click};
//...

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    $(myArray[i].key).click(myArray[i].value);
}
```